# jQuery .load page then navigate to anchor using hashtag

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need help with a jQuery function that will allow me to use hashtags to scroll to an anchor point on a .load() page.

Basically someone clicks on a homepage link and it opens up a model window that they use to navigate the remainder of the website.  This window then uses the same code to open up any other links on the site.  I know the format of these links is not optimal, but it's what I am required to work with.

I have the following code that is displayed in a model window.

```
<div id="pop-top-menu">
  <p class="p_text">
    <a href="javascript:pop('properties.php#<?php echo strip_tags($_GET['property']); ?>');">Go Back</a> |
    <a href="javascript:pop('properties.php');">View by Resorts</a> |
    <a href="javascript:pop('private-homes.php');">View our Private Homes</a> |
    <a href="javascript:pop('rental-coupons.php');">View our Properties with Discount Coupons</a></p>
</div>
```

When someone clicks on one of those links, it will then go though this code:

```
function pop(id) {
        $("#body-cover").fadeIn(1000);
        $("#slide-content").load(id).slideDown(1000);
        $("#slide-content-close").delay(2000).fadeIn(1000);
    }
```

So I need to have the visitor click on **properties.php#property_id** and it load the page properties.php and THEN navigate to the anchor tag.  Not all links will have anchors, but many will.

Please note, this is not anchor-based navigation.  This is loading a link and THEN navigating to the anchor provided (if it exists).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Untested, but when I understood your question correctly you could modify your pop function like this:

```
function pop(id) {
    // Expression to test if id has a hashtag
    var hasHash = /(#([^ ]*)/, 
        $hashID;
    $("#body-cover").fadeIn(1000);
    $("#slide-content").load(id).slideDown(1000);
    $("#slide-content-close").delay(2000).fadeIn(1000);
    if(hasHash.test(id)!== false) {
        // hasfound - grep it, and make a jQuery Object
        $hashID = $('#' + id.split('#')[1]);
        if($hashID.length) {
            // if it is found, scroll to this element with an animation
            // in case you just want a jump, simply set scrollTop 
            // and remove the animate method
            $('html, body').animate({
                 scrollTop: $hashID.offset().top
            }, 2000);
        }
    }
}
```